# FabricJS - text is not working

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I have started using FabricJS, unfortunately I can't get texts to show up. Here is my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainCanvas');
var str = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
            fontSize: 30,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            top: 50,
            left: 50,
            fill: 'black',
        });

canvas.add(str);
```

Other shapes do show up but the text just doesn't show... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, it didn't work because I have used version 0.8.32 instead of 0.9.15.

Answer (score 0):

better use Itext or Textbox if you really want to, simply replace `.text` to `.Itext`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).